# Does anybody know any Clojure machine learning framework?

Tags: clojure, machine-learning

Does anybody know any Clojure machine learning framework ? I need something what can run on top of Hadoop, similar to Weka or Mahout. I am new to Clojure and I know it is new language, is there any, just to avoid writing those stuffs in Java ( need to implement recommendation engine ).

Answer (score 7):

Clojure's interop with java is very good, so there's nothing stopping you from using weka from clojure.  If you need to create inherited classes, or classes that conform to interfaces, to operate with weka, all that can be done from within clojure.

See clojure's pages on [datatypes](http://clojure.org/datatypes) and [java interop](http://clojure.org/java_interop).

Essentially, as a clojure programmer, you should see the entire java landscape as your playground.

Comment: almost always there is someone with similar interests: http://antoniogarrote.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/visualizing-mahouts-output-with-clojure-and-incanter/

Answer (score 5):

Latests [Clj-ml](https://github.com/joshuaeckroth/clj-ml/) is alive (and has changed ownership more than once). Clj-ml 0.5.0-SNAPSHOT has support for several filters, classifiers, regression methods and clusterers. It wraps Weka, libSVM and some parts of Lucene (for computational linguistics).

Answer (score 4):

I would take a look at [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) , a java toolkit for machine learning.   In terms of using clojure real strength, its STM for concurrent programs, I think at this point in time we are left to our own devices.  good luck.

Comment: Weka isn't really built for scalable ML, which is usually the reason people would choose to implement a clojure based analytics solution

Answer (score 3):

[infer](https://github.com/aria42/infer) although not very active anymore looks like a good candidate too with a real clojure API.

Answer (score 1):

This list of "[awesome machine learning](http://www.josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning)" frameworks might be useful...